# Delphi: How can i get Handle for TComboBox component?

Tags: delphi, combobox, handle

As far as I know, Combobox consists of two components: Edit and ListBox. How can I get Handle of Combobox, if I have handle of it's Edit field ?
I tried to use GetWindow(MyHandle, GW_HWNDNEXT), where MyHandle is that handle of Edit that I know, but the result is always 0. Someone have any ideas?

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Edit window is a child of the ComboBox window: Use [`GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633510%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The down-vote makes me suspect if I have misunderstood sth. @born, are you, instead, searching for the handle of the drop-down box.

Comment: Nope, you understood me correctly. Thank you Sertac Akyuz, GetParent works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

`TCustomCombo` defines `ListHandle` and `EditHandle` properties. These have protected visibility but you can always get at them by either subclassing or using the standard trick to get at protected members:

```
type
  TCheatComboBox = class(TComboBox);

function GetListHandle(Combo: TComboBox): HWND;
begin
  Result := TCheatComboBox(Combo).ListHandle;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, but using this method i need to check every ComboBox on the form and compare value from ListHandle with MyHandle. This will work, but answer of Sertac Akyuz is a little bit better in this case. But thank you a lot!

Comment: @born2run It seems odd that you have the handle to the edit window. I'm guessing therefore that this is not a VCL form because otherwise you would start with the combo box window handle, what's known as FDropHandle in the VCL source.

Comment: Nope, that is usual VCL form. The reason that was such a situation is i used a hook. See my comment to the answer below. Thank you

Comment: @born2run I would have thought you could do all this without using a hook.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get the handle of the Edit? If you do `Combobox1.Handle` you get a handle for a `COMBOBOX` class window.

Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775792(VS.85).aspx

Comment: i used to set a hook with WH_CBT parameter. In the hook proc i catched that handle by clicking on the Edit field of some ComboBox.